# Game of choosing maximum amount after removing K coins optimally

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am given the following task to solve:
Two players play a game. In this game there are coins and each coin has a value. Each player takes turns and chooses 1 coin. The goal is to have the highest total value at the end. Each player is forced to play optionally(that means always choosing the highest value from the pile). I must find out the sum of the 2 players/the difference between their highest possible sums

Constraints: All values are natural integers and positive.

The task above is a classic greedy problem. From what I've tried it can be sorted with quickSort and then just picking the elements in order for the 2 players. If you need a better time on my tests Radix-Sort performs better. Ok so this task is pretty easy.

Now I have the same task as above BUT the first player must remove OPTIMALLY K coins such that the difference between their scores is maximal. Well this sounds like DP but my mind can't come up with the solution. I must find out again the maximal difference between their points(with both players playing optimally). Or the points of the 2 players in such a way that the difference between them is maximal.

Is there such an algorithm already implemented? Or can someone give me some tips on this issue?

Comment: I don't understand the rules well, could you provide a simple example ?

Comment: Sure let's say we have the values: 9 7 and 2. The first player must eliminate 1 coin in order to maximize the difference between their scores. So the first player decides to eliminate the coin with value 7. He picks the coin with value 9 and the other player is left with a coin of value 2 -> the difference between their sums is 7

Comment: @m.raynal you are right I did a poor job at explaining. I should have mentioned that you must remove the K coins in such a way that the difference between the scores is the highest.

Comment: So it means that in the 'normal' game (the first rules you describe) a player must first eliminate a coin from the game, and then must pick another coin. So ultimately in this version, there are 2 coins less in the game after each turn, and the greedy approach is then to select the highest value coin for oneself, and eliminate the second highest value coin to prevent the opponent from using it. Do I get it right ?

Comment: @m.raynal No. In the normal game you just have the coins and each player must PICK coins to keep(at the end we sum up the value of the coins and see who has more, so each player must pick the highest value coin on the field). In the 2nd variant the first player must remove k coins from the game first. Then the game starts.(the k coins must be removed in such a way that the difference between the score of the first player and the 2nd player to be maximal with both players playing to win so choosing coins to have the highest possible sum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a DP approach solution. We consider `n` coins, sorted by descending order to simplify the notation (meaning `coins[0]` is the highest value coin, while `coins[n-1]` has the lowest value), and we want to remove `k` coins in order to win the game with a margin as big as possible.
We will consider a matrix `M`, of dimensions `n-k` per `k`.
`M` stores the following: `M(i, j)` is the **best possible score after playing `i` turns, when `j` coins have been  removed out of the `i+j` best coins**. It may sound a bit counter-intuitive at first, but it actually is what we are looking for.
Indeed, we have already a value to initialize our matrix: `M(0, 0) = 0`.
We also can see that `M(n-k, k)` is actually the solution to the problem we want to solve.
We now need recurrence equations to fill up our matrix. We consider that we want to maximize the score difference for the first player. To maximize the score difference for the second player, the approach is the same, just modify some signs.

```
if i = 0 then:
    M(i, j) = 0  // score difference is always 0 after playing 0 turns
else if j = 0 and i % 2 = 0:  // player 1 plays
    M(i, j) = M(i-1, j) + coins[i+j]
else if j = 0 and i % 2 = 1:  // player 2 plays
    M(i, j) = M(i-1, j) - coins[i+j]
else if i % 2 = 0:
    M(i, j) = max(M(i, j-1), M(i-1, j) + coins[i+j])
else if i % 2 = 1:
    M(i, j) = max(M(i, j-1), M(i-1, j) - coins[i+j])
```

This recurrence simply means that the best choice, at any point, is between removing the coin (in the case where the best value is `M(i, j-1)`), or not removing it(case where the best value is `M(i-1, j) +/- coins[i+j]`) .
That will give you the final score difference, but not the set of coins to remove. To find it, you must keep the 'optimal path' that your program used to calculate the matrix values (was the best value coming from M(i-1,j) or from M(i,j-1) ?).
This path can give you the set you are looking for. By the way, you can see this makes sense, as there are `k among n` possible ways to remove `k` coins out of `n` coins, and there are as well `k among n` paths from top left to bottom right in a `k` per `n-k` matrix if you're allowed to go right or down only.
This explanation might still be unclear, do not hesitate to ask precisions in the comment, I'll edit the answer for more clarity.

Comment: Actually atm ifor me it makes a lot of sense. I didn't manage to think of: M(i, j) = max(M(i, j-1), M(i-1, j) + coins[i+j]). That max thing. I will however ask in the short future more questions if I can't understand something while I am implementing it. 

But this is the right answer so I will mark it as such.

Comment: Oh! @m.raynal what I get in M(n-k, k) is actually the highest sum possible by player one from my understanding. However I need the sum of player 2 also. My answer must be the maximal difference between the score of player 1 and player 2. This is what I must find out. So my matrix would have to contain either both scores or each value has to be the maximal difference between the scores of the 2 players. And I must pick the maximal one.

Does this make sense?

Comment: The value stored is actually the difference, since when it is player one playing (when `i % 2 = 0`), we add the value of `coin[i+j]`, while when it is player 2's turn, we substract `coins[i+j]`.

Comment: Ah, right. I noticed when I started implementing. Thank you very much!